# how to get unique ID of Video

Tags: android

In my application I'm trying to display the list of videos in a list view in one `Activity` and I'm trying to display the thumbnail of selected video in another `Activity` for I got a code to display the thumbnail in `ImageView`,

```
iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagePreview);
ContentResolver crThumb = getContentResolver();
BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 1;
Bitmap curThumb = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(crThumb, id, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, options);
iv.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
iv.setImageBitmap(curThumb);
```

in this it displays the thumbnail only if I specify a integer value for `id` in

```
Bitmap curThumb = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(crThumb, id, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, options);
```

but what I want is to get the `id` value for selected video so that I can display it new `Activity` as I wish.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] projection = { BaseColumns._ID, MediaColumns.DATA };               
Cursor cursor = managedQuery(data, projection, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(BaseColumns._ID);
int id = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
```

This code will help you, "data" is the uri of selected video

Comment: Sure about the fact that the code works? I tried to use - Uri videoUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(videoFilePath)); - to obtain the uri to use, but call to managequery always returns a null object. And yes, videoFilePath is a working path

Comment: the data should be content Uri not file Uri.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:  Detail [Click Here](http://androidcodezs.blogspot.com/2013/10/android-thumbnail-from-video.html)

```
int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID));
String[] thumbColumns = { MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.DATA,
MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.VIDEO_ID};
Cursor thumbCursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
thumbColumns, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.VIDEO_ID + "=" + id, null, null);
if (thumbCursor.moveToFirst()) {
       Log.v("VideoGallery",thumbCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.DATA));
}
```